# PHP Instagram клиент

Tags: php, парсер, api, instagram

Сейчас занимаюсь созданием парсера инстаграмм-профилей, и все хорошо работает, т.к. есть много данных по адресу

https://www.instagram.com/ ник пользователя /?__a=1

Но есть проблема: приватные профили. Гуглил много, повсюду только способы выставлять посты и сторис, но ни слова о подписке на другие профили и их просмотр.

Есть ли какой-то способ войти в инстаграмм, следить за приватными профилями и качать посты через API?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел очень хорошую библиотеку - raiym/instagram-php-scraper

++ phpfastcashe/phpfastcashe

Работает отлично и стабильно, инстаграм думает, что пользователь сидит с телефона. Вхожу через свой профиль, все приватные каналы теперь доступны